# iOS: Instruments shows imageio_png_data is 300x larger in size than its actual image size

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments, xcode-instruments

I have an image that is only 28KB in size:
[image]

I'm adding it to my view using this code:

```
  UIImageView *background = [UIImageView new];
  background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1080, 1920);
  background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Submit.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:background];
```

Now I'm profiling with Instruments Allocation and "Marking Generation" right before and right after the image is allocated:

[image]

Instruments indicates that it took 7.92MB to load the image into memory.
I'm seeing the same issue with other images as well.
Why is ImageIO_PNG_Data at 7.92MB when the image is only 28KB in size?

Comment: Images have to be decompressed to be rendered in a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because a PNG is compressed data describing what the image looks like, so a PNG that is nothing but a solid color is tiny because it is easy to describe. But the bitmap is the bitmap - just a grid of pixels - and depends purely on the dimensions of the image (which, in your case, is immense).

Comment: I converted the file to jpg format from png which saved up all that space. But now I'm losing the transparent background so that's obviously no good. Is there a preferred practice to deal with this issue?

Comment: What "issue" do you mean? So far you have just described the normal world. What's the problem?

Comment: Good point. Suppose I have a full screen image that I want to display, such as the login screen. If I could use a jpg image it wouldn't take up much memory and there would be no problem. But parts of that full screen image need to transparent, so I have to use GIF or PNG for that. But those need to be uncompressed, and the uncompressed version is 300 times bigger than the compressed version, getting up to 8MB per full screen png image. Is there a better approach?

Comment: 8 MB is not very much in the grand scheme of things. You can save a little memory by scaling the image down first if the screen is smaller than your 1080 by 1920, but otherwise, don't worry, be happy.

Comment: thanks :) The issue is that when I look at my allocations, the app spikes from 40MB to 120MB when I launch this screen that has about ten pngs in it, and when I dismiss the screen it stays at 120MB ... making me wonder if the system is caching them. Eventually the app does crash from memory pressure. So I'm not so happy :(

Comment: You said _one_ png. Where did _ten_ pngs come from? And how can they possibly all be 1080 by 1920, all at the same time? You can't possibly show them all at once - the screen isn't that big. This makes no sense. Explain.

Comment: Yes sir! I have a lot of screens that I'm using a 1080x1920 image for, with about 9MB per uncompressed ImageIO_PNG_Data. These are persisting in memory even after I dismiss the View Controller that they are allocated with.

Comment: Why? Is the view controller leaking? If so, _that_ is what you need to be asking a question about. Yes, images are big, but seeing that many of them do not accumulate in memory at once is _your_ responsibility. Implement `dealloc` or `deinit` on your view controller to log and see that your view controller is in fact going out of existence when you think it should.

Answer (score 4):

@matt and @dan really did a good job of explaining why an uncompressed image should take up literally 300X memory of the actual PNG image size to display on the screen. What makes this issue worse is that the iOS caches these images and does NOT release them from cache EVER, even on memory warnings.

So here's a way to prevent image caching on iOS to save up a ton of memory, just use imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageNamed:

Replace:

```
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Submit.png"];
```

With:

```
background.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Submit.png"]];
```

and now the ImageIO_PNG_Data's will be released when the view controller is dismissed.

It's all right here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to
>   ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should
>   instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will
>   keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially
>   improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Comment: "and does NOT release them from cache EVER, even on memory warnings." I don't believe that. I think something is wrong with how you're testing. Or something else is going on.

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile:
"This method does not cache the image object.". @matt - must say I haven't tested this thoroughly so you may very well be correct

Comment: Oh, of course it is well known and well documented that `imageNamed:` caches and that `imageWithContentsOfFile:` does not. That is an important difference between them. But `imageNamed:` does not cache to the point where you crash! That would be ridiculous. It caches to your benefit (so that opening the same image again is fast), not to your detriment. If you are crashing because you're running out of memory, I do not believe you are crashing because you use `imageNamed:`. I believe, as I have said all along, that something else is going on.

Comment: Learnt one thing `imageNamed:` caches and that `imageWithContentsOfFile:` does not, thank you @matt